# Given a file, find the ten most frequently occurring words as efficiently as possible

Tags: string, algorithm, language-agnostic

This is apparently an interview question (found it in a collection of interview questions), but even if it's not it's pretty cool.

We are told to do this efficiently on all complexity measures. I thought of creating a HashMap that maps the words to their frequency. That would be O(n) in time and space complexity, but since there may be lots of words we cannot assume that we can store everything in memory.

I must add that nothing in the question says that the words cannot be stored in memory, but what if that were the case? If that's not the case, then the question does not seem as challenging.

Comment: Something Irrelevant : where did you find the collection of Interview Questions?

Comment: It's a book that a friend of mine lent me. The following website claims to have collection of Google interview questions though. http://blog.seattleinterviewcoach.com/2009/02/140-google-interview-questions.html#software_engineer

Comment: Storing them in a hash map is O(n) but that doesn't give you the top 10 without, say, a subsequent O(n log n) sort.

Comment: @John That's true. Bad mistake.

Comment: @John Depending on n, it may be faster to do 10 linear searches which is technically O(n).

Comment: @John Kugelman you can find the top 10 in much less than O(n log(n))--why sort the entire data structure when you only need to pull out the top ten?

Comment: Apparently a full day's worth of interview questions isn't THAT good an idea after all. I'll edit it again. Thanks for pointing these things out guys.

Comment: @robert: How else would you *get* the top 10?

Comment: @Victor We can just keep track of the top ten frequencies, doing only a linear pass.

Comment: If there are 15 words that have the same highest frequency, I assume we "return" the 10 words which occurred first ?

Comment: @Muggen The question says nothing about breaking ties, so I assume we can return any 10 out of those 15.

Comment: "on all complexity measures"? there's an O(1) space (if "10" is a constant), O(n^2) time algorithm, and an O(n) space and O(n) time algorithm, so which is better on all complexity measures?

Comment: @John n != n in this case, though.  It doesn't change the big Oh / complexity, but it would be more efficient to sort the list than traverse the file if the list has fewer than log(n) elements (where n is the number of words in the file.  Big Oh isn't always foolproof!

Comment: The most important part of this question is what do you mean by "We cannot assume that we can store everything in memory"? If you're talking about about actual RAM, then by the time you get to a data set big enough to fill your RAM, the added time complexity introduced by a smaller space complexity algorithm will likely be greater than the time saved not having to use your hard drive. If you're talking total space (RAM + hard drive), then unless you have an algorithm that only requires sequential access to the data, it will require `O(n)` space for random access anyways.

Comment: There is a paper on this topic: https://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~farach/pubs/FrequentStream.pdf

Answer (score 20):

Optimizing for my own time:

```
sort file | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -10
```

Possibly followed by `awk '{print $2}'` to eliminate the counts.

Comment: What does this mean? Can anyone explain please?

Comment: `sort` groups like words together.  `uniq -c` counts each group and prints one line with the count and the group.  `sort -nr` sorts `n`umerically (now by count) `r`eversed so the highest count is first.  `head -10` prints the top 10.  The optional `awk` chops off the counts.

Comment: If a line may contain more than one word, use `tr` to split the lines:   `tr ' ' '\n' < text | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -10`

Answer (score 13):

I think the [trie data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) is a choice.

In the trie, you can record word count in each node representing frequency of word consisting of characters on the path from root to current node.

The time complexity to setup the trie is O(Ln) ~ O(n) (where L is number of characters in the longest word, which we can treat as a constant). To find the top 10 words, we can traversal the trie, which also costs O(n). So it takes O(n) to solve this problem.

Comment: Actually, traversing the trie costs at worst ~O(Lt), where t is the token count which can be no greater than N, and L is as above.  It just seems to me that there ought to be a fundamentally faster way to go about this.

Comment: @JakeKurzer it is not about to be the fastest in these interviews, but to show the interviewer that you're able to discuss alternatives and trade-offs.

Comment: "Rule of Economy: Programmer time is expensive; conserve it in preference to machine time." - Rob Pike

Answer (score 4):

An complete solution would be something like this:

1. Do an external sort O(N log N)
2. Count the word freq in the file O(N)
3. (An alternate would be the use of a Trie as @Summer_More_More_Tea to count the frequencies, if you can afford that amount of memory) O(k*N) //for the two first steps
4. Use a min-heap:

   - Put the first n elements on the heap
   - For every word left add it to the heap and delete the new min in heap
   - In the end the heap Will contain the n-th most common words O(|words|*log(n))

With the Trie the cost would be O(k*N), because the number of total words generally is bigger than the size of the vocabulary. Finally, since k is smaller for most of the western languages you could assume a linear complexity.

Answer (score 2):

I have done in C# like this(a sample)

```
int wordFrequency = 10;
string words = "hello how r u u u u  u  u u  u  u u u  u u u u  u u u ? hello there u u u u ! great to c u there. hello .hello hello hello hello hello .hello hello hello hello hello hello ";            

var result = (from word in words.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                          group word by word into g
                          select new { Word = g.Key, Occurance = g.Count() }).ToList().FindAll(i => i.Occurance >= wordFrequency);
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's say we assign a random prime number to each of the 26 letters in the Latin alphabet. Then we scan the file. Whenever we find a word, we calculate its hash value (formula based on the position & the value of the letters making the word). If we find this value in the hash table, then we know for sure that we are not encountering it for the first time and we increment its count. And maintain an array of the top 10. But whenever we encounter a new hash value, then we store the file pointer for it, and initialize the count to 0.

Comment: What do the file positions get used for? What do the prime numbers get used for - is the arbitrary prime the *value of [each letter] making the word*?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a typical application of counting sort since the sum of occurrences of each word is equal to the total number of words. A hash table with a counting sort should do the job in a time proportional to the number of words.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a time/space tradeoff and go `O(n^2)` for time and `O(1)` for (memory) space by counting how many times a word occurs each time you encounter it in a linear pass of the data. If the count is above the top 10 found so far, then keep the word and the count, otherwise ignore it.

Comment: You'll have to keep every word, otherwise every time you see a word not in the top 10 you'll think it's the first time you saw it.

Comment: But thinking that is OK, because it's still `O(n^2)`. The only time it's an issue is when it is a word in the top 10 (because you might keep the same word 10 times), but we do keep those words, so it's not a big issue. Thinking it's the first time every time does not mean we "have to keep every word". As I said above, you count "each time you encounter it." Not as time efficient of course, but OP wants space efficiency.

Comment: Consider a file in which the second half of the file in the same word, repeated.  If you process the file linearly, once you get to the sceond half you will already have your 'top 10' words that you've kept.  You'll see this word, and count '1'.  Not in the top 10, don't keep it; move to the next word.  See it again - I haven't 'kept' it, so I haven't counted it, so count '1'.  Not in the top 10, don't keep it; move to the next word.  Repeat.  Can you explain what I'm missing?

Comment: @Kirk The algorithm you describe is only `O(n)` time-wise (or maybe `O(n log n)`?). I'm suggesting an `O(n^2)` algorithm where you "count how many times a word occurs each time you encounter it" -- in other words, for each word in text, compare each word in text and count the number of times the two are the same. As far as code goes, it would look like `for(i=0; i < num_words; ++i) { for (j=0; j < num_words; ++j) { if (words[i] == words[j]) ++count; }` plus some code at the end to process whether the count is in the top 10 or not and if the word has already been included in the top 10.

Answer (score 1):

Says building a Hash and sorting the values is best. I'm inclined to agree.
http://www.allinterview.com/showanswers/56657.html

Here is a Bash implementation that does something similar...I think
http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/5994/computes-the-most-frequent-used-words-of-a-text-file

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the size of the input data, it may or may not be a good idea to keep a HashMap. Say for instance, our hash-map is too big to fit into main memory. This can cause a very high number of memory transfers as most hash-map implementations need random access and would not be very good on the cache.

In such cases sorting the input data would be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Cycle through the string of words and store each in a dictionary(using python) and number of times they occur as the value.

Comment: A Python dictionary is a HashMap, so that's pretty much what I proposed.

Answer (score 0):

If the word list will not fit in memory, you can split the file until it will.  Generate a histogram of each part (either sequentially or in parallel), and merge the results (the details of which may be a bit fiddly if you want guaranteed correctness for all inputs, but should not compromise the O(n) effort, or the O(n/k) time for k tasks).

Answer (score 0):

A [Radix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree) or one of it's variations will generally allow you to save storage space by collapsing common sequences.
Building it will take O(nk) - where k is "the maximum length of all strings in the set".

Answer (score 0):

**step 1** : If the file is very large and can't be sorted in memory you can split it into chunks that can be sorted in memory.

**step 2** : For each sorted chunk compute sorted pairs of (words, nr_occurrence), at his point you can renounce to the chunks because you need only the sorted pairs.

**step 3** : Iterate over the chunks and sort the chunks and always keep the top ten appearances.

Example:

**Step 1**:

a b a ab abb a a b b c c ab ab

split into :

chunk 1: a b a ab
chunk 2: abb a a b b
chunk 3: c c ab ab

**Step 2**:

chunk 1:  a2, b1, ab1
chunk 2:  a2, b2, abb1
chunk 3:  c2, ab2

**Step 3**(merge the chunks and keep the top ten appearances):

a4 b3 ab3  c2 abb1

Answer (score 0):

```
    int k = 0;
    int n = i;
    int j;
    string[] stringList = h.Split(" ".ToCharArray(),
                                  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    int m = stringList.Count();
    for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        int c = 0;
        for (k = 0; k < m; k++)
        {
            if (string.Compare(stringList[j], stringList[k]) == 0)
            {
                c = c + 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not sure your code solves desired problem - case where words aren't stored in memory

Answer (score 0):

Not the most efficient CPU-wise, and UGLY, but it took only 2 minutes to bang out:

`perl -lane '$h{$_}++ for @F; END{for $w (sort {$h{$b}<=>$h{$a}} keys %h) {print "$h{$w}\t$w"}}' file | head`

Loop over each line with `-n`
Split each line into `@F` words with `-a`
Each `$_` word increments hash `%h`
Once the `END` of `file` has been reached,
`sort` the hash by the frequency
Print the frequency `$h{$w}` and the word `$w`
Use bash `head` to stop at 10 lines

Using the text of this web page as input:

```
121     the
77      a
48      in
46      to
44      of
39      at
33      is
30      vote
29      and
25      you
```

I benchmarked this solution vs the top-rated shell solution (ben jackson) on a 3.3GB text file with 580,000,000 words.
Perl 5.22 completed in 171 seconds, while the shell solution completed in 474 seconds.