# Is there a way to print image histogram statistics in terminal?

Tags: linux, image, image-processing, terminal, histogram

I was wondering what would be the easiest way to get mean, mode and median from image histogram. I am especially interested in **mode** **value**. To clarify, I am looking for something like:

> histogram-statistics image.jpg

and output like this:

```
Mean:128
Median: 120
Mode: 90
```

Comment: Do you want this for colour or greyscale images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use ImageMagick's `identify` command:

```
identify -verbose image1.png 
Image: image1.png
  Format: PNG (Portable Network Graphics)
  Mime type: image/png
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 150x150+0+0
  Units: Undefined
  Type: PaletteAlpha
  Endianess: Undefined
  Colorspace: sRGB
  Depth: 8-bit
  Channel depth:
    red: 8-bit
    green: 8-bit
    blue: 8-bit
    alpha: 8-bit
  Channel statistics:
    Pixels: 22500
    Red:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 83.8114 (0.328672)
      standard deviation: 103.634 (0.406408)
      kurtosis: -1.14294
      skewness: 0.82261
    Green:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 87.1483 (0.341758)
      standard deviation: 84.6068 (0.331791)
      kurtosis: -1.04099
      skewness: 0.547178
    Blue:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 68.5556 (0.268846)
      standard deviation: 75.6456 (0.29665)
      kurtosis: -0.809854
      skewness: 0.696317
    Alpha:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 160.584 (0.629743)
      standard deviation: 122.279 (0.479526)
      kurtosis: -1.69938
      skewness: 0.537413
  Image statistics:
    Overall:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 83.4827 (0.327383)
      standard deviation: 98.1998 (0.385097)
      kurtosis: -1.04514
      skewness: 0.753059
  Alpha: none   #00000000
  Colors: 87
  Histogram:
      8120: (  0,  0,  0,  0) #00000000 none
      6180: ( 27, 71,148,255) #1B4794 srgba(27,71,148,1)
       109: ( 41, 78,140,255) #294E8C srgba(41,78,140,1)
        71: ( 41, 81,140,255) #29518C srgba(41,81,140,1)
 ...
 ...
```

The mode is not in there, unless you use the histogram, but you could calculate it easily enough using `awk` if you convert the image to ASCII numbers like this using `NetPBM`'s `PPM` format ([see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm)):

```
convert image1.png -compress none ppm:- | awk ...
```

Comment: Thank you!
I combined your method with this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4495357/3084276

I ended up using:
convert image1.png -compress none ppm:-|tr ' ' '\n' | sort|uniq -c|sort -nr | head -10